# Why wont this basic command even open

Tags: batch-file

```
@Echo off
goto Home
:Home
color 74
echo.
echo.
echo |||||       ||||||||       |||||   |||||||||||||   |||||          |||||||      ||||||   ||||||||         ||||||||   |||||||||||||
echo   \\\        ///\\\        ///        |||    |||     |||         |||   |||    |||  |||     |||\\\        ///|||        |||    |||
echo    \\\      ///  \\\      ///         |||            |||        |||          |||    |||    ||| \\\      /// |||        |||
echo     \\\    ///    \\\    ///          ||||||         |||        |||          |||    |||    |||  \\\    ///  |||        ||||||
echo      \\\  ///      \\\  ///           |||            |||        |||          |||    |||    |||   \\\  ///   |||        |||
echo       \\\///        \\\///            |||    |||     |||    |||  |||   |||    |||  |||     |||    \\\///    |||        |||    |||
echo      ||||||||      |||||||||        ||||||||||||    |||||||||||   |||||||      ||||||    |||||||  ||||||  |||||||    ||||||||||||
echo.
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS-----------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo   1) Open Calculator                    2) Open Game                         3)Exit                         4) Admin Access
pause
```

Comment: Because there is something wrong. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! Just dropping code is definitely not a good and specific question!

Answer (score 2):

The pipe symbol has a function. You have to either put the lines in double quotes or to escape every single `|` with a caret `^|` BTW you need a console width of at least 130 to display without line breaks.

```
@Echo off
echo "|||||      ||||||||       |||||"
echo " \\\        ///\\\        ///   "
echo "  \\\      ///  \\\      ///    "
echo "   \\\    ///    \\\    ///     "
echo "    \\\  ///      \\\  ///      "
echo "     \\\///        \\\///       "
echo "    ||||||||      |||||||||     "
pause
```

---

```
@Echo off
echo ^|^|^|^|^|      ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|       ^|^|^|^|^|
echo  \\\        ///\\\        ///   
echo   \\\      ///  \\\      ///    
echo    \\\    ///    \\\    ///     
echo     \\\  ///      \\\  ///      
echo      \\\///        \\\///       
echo     ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|      ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|     
pause
```

Both batch versions display correctly:

```
|||||      ||||||||       |||||
 \\\        ///\\\        ///
  \\\      ///  \\\      ///
   \\\    ///    \\\    ///
    \\\  ///      \\\  ///
     \\\///        \\\///
    ||||||||      |||||||||
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it actually open but close very quickly as there is no pause.

Try to add "timeout /t 10" at the end of the file and to put double quotes all around your text

```
color 74
echo
echo
echo "|||||       ||||||||       |||||   |||||||||||||   |||||          |||||||      ||||||   ||||||||         ||||||||   |||||||||||||"
echo  " \\\        ///\\\        ///        |||    |||     |||         |||   |||    |||  |||     |||\\\        ///|||        |||    |||"
echo   " \\\      ///  \\\      ///         |||            |||        |||          |||    |||    ||| \\\      /// |||        |||"
echo   "  \\\    ///    \\\    ///          ||||||         |||        |||          |||    |||    |||  \\\    ///  |||        ||||||"
echo    "  \\\  ///      \\\  ///           |||            |||        |||          |||    |||    |||   \\\  ///   |||        |||"
echo    "   \\\///        \\\///            |||    |||     |||    |||  |||   |||    |||  |||     |||    \\\///    |||        |||    |||"
echo    "  ||||||||      |||||||||        ||||||||||||    |||||||||||   |||||||      ||||||    |||||||  ||||||  |||||||    ||||||||||||"
echo
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS-----------------------------------------------"
echo
echo
echo   "1) Open Calculator                    2) Open Game                         3)Exit                         4) Admin Access"
timeout /t 10
```

With this, there are lot of graphic bug (the welcome do not print correctly) but the window stay there for 10 seconds (or until you press a key)